# How to split html pages at section level in bookdown

Tags: r-markdown, bookdown

I have a bookdown/rmarkdown gitbook with separate Rmd files for each chapter. Each chapter contains several sections and subsections. I'd like the webbrowser to only load one section at a time the same way YiHui's bookdown text does (at https://bookdown.org/yihui/bookdown/), but I simply cannot find any way to do that.

I've tried adding `split_by: section` in my `_output.yml` file, but that didn't work.

===

EDIT: I was putting the `split_by: section` is the wrong place. It is supposed to go directly under `bookdown::gitbook:` whereas I was putting it under `config:`. I found this out by realizing I could view the source of YiHui's book on github.